# How can I record my bash session as an executable?

Tags: bash, server, admin

I want to login to a server.  Then run a series of bash commands installing programs and setting configurations.  I want these commands to be recorded into an executable script that I can subsequently run on similar servers to automate setup.  How do I do this?

I'm familiar with the `script` command, but this is not what I want because it does not create executable scripts.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script

Comment: @hek2mgl I know what a shell script is and how to write one by hand.  But I'll be typing in several thousand commands, and I don't want to write that shell script manually.  I want a program that will record my bash session and create the shell script for me automatically.

Comment: First, I did not downvote because I expected something like this, your question might have mentioned that you know what a shell script is.. About the topic. Usually, if you type *several thousands* of commands, there are typos and errors in them. I would not auto-record them. I would simply use the bash history and grab the commands from there. Btw, I can't believe that you are typing several thousands of commands manually.

Comment: I thought Everyone knew what a shell script is :)  Yes, many of the commands will be redundant, but I don't care.  I just don't want to have to manually curate the list of commands.  I want to reproduce my session exactly in a fully automated way.

Comment: For me this sounds really dirty and fragile. I sugest to use the bash history, manually pick commands of interest, remove redundancy, use variable, loops, etc and make a bullet proof shell script out of it.

Comment: But that would be several days of work.  I am certain that I want what I asked for and not something else.

Answer (score 2):

Though you should look again at `script`, there is also **autoexpect** which is part of the `expect` package. It will record interactions for replay, including commands which prompt for yes/no and similar answers.

Comment: Can you explain how `script` would work for this?  I've used `autoexpect` before, but this doesn't work for me because it would need to be installed on the target systems before I can use it.  I need the output to be a shell script.

Comment: `script` will simply provide you with a complete reminder of eveything you typed. If you used vi or graphical dialogues, this is not much good, but can help you convert what you did into some equivalent like `sed -i /somefile '/abc/s/=x/=y/'`. Often I setup a config in an editor, then rewrite that as a sed script.  You can also use `diff` to save the changes and `patch` to apply them on another machine.  `autoexpect` can be run before you ssh to the remote.

Comment: That sounds like a recipe for making a minor mistake that causes my script to not reproduce my previous session.

Comment: you could just do all the machines at the same time. see for example
[this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19010/119298).

Comment: That won't work for me because not all the machines will be running at once.